# i want to go 0,10 from 5,6 with dijsktra or similar and i want to write path explained in code i'm bad at coding :D so its loop infinite times

Tags: c++, dijkstra, maze

every time in this loop until reach target and source same x and y cordinates then its already
count distance this loop check every parent locations right bottom top left its not working
because i really dont know how fix it :D also I want to locations of path in kont matrix its
really simple but I'm stuck I dont know how to get out

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i,j;

        row      column
    int satir=11,stun=13;
```

this is the map I want to use 0 means wall and 1 mean road that
you can move ofc

```
    int harita[satir][stun] =
    {
        {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},
        {0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0},
        {0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0},
        {0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0},
        {1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0},
        {0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0},
        {0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
        {0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0},
        {0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},
        {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    };
```

I just want to write the map on cmd for check

```
    for(i=0; i<satir; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<stun; j++)
        {
           cout<<" "<<harita[i][j];
        }

        cout<<endl;
    }


      // the path i want to write like kont[0][10],kont[0][9],kont[0][8],kont[0][7],kont[0][6],kont[1][6]
      int kont[satir][stun];


      // distance


    int mesafe=0;


      // source location start


    int dx=0,dy=10;


      // target location


    int xk=5,yk=6;
```

every time in this loop until reach target and source same x and y cordinates then its already
count distance this loop check every parent locations right bottom top left its not working ofc
because I really dont know how fix it :D also i want to locations of path in kont matrix its
really simple but I'm stuck I dont know how to get out

```
    while(1)
    {



        if( dx == xk && dy == yk )
        {
            cout<<"mesafe budur="<<mesafe;




  // if source and target same location write the distance and exit while loop


            exit(1);
        }

         // for check loop count

         // ofc infinite now

        cout<<"kertenkele";
```

for finding shortest path and I gonna use it later

```
        kont[dx][dy]=1;
```

everytime its check 4 if then if there is no wall its move there if there is a way its goes
left right top bottom until reach the target x and y cordinates

for go bottom

```
        if(harita[dx+1][dy]==1)
        {
            dx++;
            mesafe++;
        }
```

for go right

```
        if(harita[dx][dy+1]==1)
        {
        dy++;
        mesafe++;
        }
```

for go up

```
        if(harita[dx-1][dy]==1)
        {
            dx--;
            mesafe++;
            }
```

going for left everytime in loop its check evey neighboor until reach target

```
        if(harita[dx][dy-1]==1)
        {
            dy--;
            mesafe++;
            }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

the problem is about the good its loop infinite time and I think I don't really understand

how I get datas from loop

Comment: You need to use backtracking. Read up more on it (maybe start [here](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/basic-programming/recursion/recursion-and-backtracking/tutorial/)) and then attempt this problem. The problem with your code is that you aren't storing your choices and are _greedily_ navigating the maze (`harita` in your case). Understand it like this: if at a certain point in a map, you have 3 choices, going up, down or right and you choose going up but hit a wall after few steps. You need to come back and try going right and if even that doesn't work, try going down.

Comment: dude if i get this topic already i never been asking this question :D i just a little bit example on my code i know i'm greedy but i really dont get it backtracking